# Is there any way to remove all remote notifications that are one day old?

Tags: ios, swift, remote-notifications

Is there any way to remove all remote notifications that are one day old?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications { notifications in

    let yesterday = NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date())!

    let identifiersToRemove = notifications
        .filter { $0.date.compare(yesterday) == .orderedAscending }
        .map { $0.request.identifier }

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: identifiersToRemove)
}
```